# Conditional formating: Highlight group of cells if they contain less than 2 of a specified character

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a group of 4 cells that I need a conditional format to highlight if they contain less than 2 of a particular character. Lets say in this case we are looking for "^".

So if there is more than one then nothing will be highlighted like this

[image]

but if there is 1 then it needs to highlight that one

[image]

if there are none then it should highlight all 4 cells

[image]

I tried using the SEARCH and COUNTIF in the conditional format formula but I cant seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=OR(AND(NOT(ISERR(FIND("^",A1))),
        SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISERR(FIND("^",A$1:A$4))))=1),
    SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISERR(FIND("^",A$1:A$4))))=0)
```

The output:

[image: Conditional Formatting]

**Explanation:**

The FIND function raises a #VALUE! error if it can't find the search string.

The second FIND, which appears as the second argument to AND, checks if "^" is contained in any cell within the range A1:A4. This returns an array of values, which is converted to boolean array by the ISERR. The NOT inverts each boolean value in the array and the double minus (--) converts the booleans into numbers (FALSE into 0, TRUE into 1). The SUMPRODUCT sums up the final array and we check if the resulting sum is equal to 1.

So that satisfies the first part of the first condition; i.e., this part tells us whether "^" appears exactly in one cell within the range.

Then, the first FIND function checks if the "^" appears in the current cell, as opposed to the entire range. So when the conditional format is applied to cell A2, this part checks if "^" appears in A2. The rest of the part (NOT, ISERR) does the same thing.

These two conditions need to be satisfied simultaneously, and hence, we wrap AND around these two. This completes the first argument of OR.

The second part of OR represents the second condition, which is the same as the second argument of the AND function we saw previously, except that this one checks if the sum of the array is equal to 0, i.e., no cells with "^" have been found.

Unlike in the first argument of OR, we don't restrict this with AND function since we want all the cells to be coloured, not just the relative cell where the "^" appears.

Comment: This is what I was looking for in one combined solution thanks again!

Comment: Would you be able to explain the formula for future users that are looking for a similar solution so they will be able to understand it?

Comment: @MatthewLozoya, sure, I'll add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For first thing do nothing
for second thing create formula:

```
=AND(COUNTIF($A:$A;"*^*")=1;FIND("^";A1)>1)
```

for third thing create formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A;"*^*")=0
```

Comment: I might be able to combine this to my needs let me test this out

Comment: This works with the two formula method you suggested I am hoping to combine it to one whole formula I will try to work this out